# Use Adobe Reader online / view comments without installing Reader

Tags: macos, pdf, adobe-acrobat, adobe-reader, annotations

Is there a way to run Adobe Reader without installing it locally on my machine (e.g. in the cloud or on a jump drive)? On Macs, it is sometimes possible to run programs directly from a disk image without install, which would be another possibility.

This is possible with many applications, but unfortunately I have not found a good way to do this with Adobe Reader specifically. For security reasons, I cannot run Adobe Reader, but I frequently receive PDFs from coworkers with annotations / comments that can only be read inside of Adobe Reader.

Comment: Many 3rd party PDF utilities do not support the advanced PDF features. Further, research indicates there does not appear to be a portable version of Adobe PDF reader.

Answer (score -1):

I think Kami might work. You should try it.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kami-pdf-and-document-mar/iljojpiodmlhoehoecppliohmplbgeij?hl=en

Comment: Right now this is a link-only answer, which are not considered helpful on SuperUser. OP has several specific features they need. Please at least provide evidence that the product you are recommending meets these requirements.